# Phoenix websocket socket.disconnect() vs. channel.leave()

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm reading through the [phoenix docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/js/) on ways to disconnect from a socket or leave a channel.

My naive understanding is that `channel#leave`

> Unsubscribes from server events, and instructs the channel to terminate on server

and `socket#disconnect` maintains the channel server-side, allowing for reconnection.

So, my question is when to use one vs. the other.

It sounds like there are 2 cases to consider:

1. There are other clients subscribed to the same channel, so `#leave` would cut-off their connection, favoring a `#disconnect`.
2. But if there is user/account attrition, NEVER calling `leave` maintains "dead" channels on the server and for long-running processes this could be an issue?

Am I thinking about this correctly? Should we implement periodic cleanup tasks to kill long-running, "dead" channels if we choose to roll with `#disconnect`-only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Phoenix's real-time interface is built on two default public abstractions, a socket interface, through which a client connects - this is usually a websocket (although it can fall back to longpolling or use other transports), this is the "wire" that is created between a client and your server. Usually you mediate this connection through means of a token, to decide if the client is able to open that socket connection. It's specified in `user_socket.ex`.

And then you have the channel interface, which is a gen_server with specific handles (api) tailored to receive incoming messages through the "wire". You can also have authorising logic to allow subscription to a channel ("joining"), and it can vary by channel (or even topic).

Each client can be connected to 1 socket and 0 to N channels. A client being connected to a channel, underneath, is simply (simplified) registering a given socket to a Publisher Subscriber interface (Phoenix's PubSub) and having a process for those "channel:room" for each socket subscribed to that particular combination.

If you fire up `:observer.start` from your `iex` shell, and go to the `Processes` tab, and then join, from two different clients, the same exact "channel:topic" you'll see there will be two channel processes, not one. If you see the Application tree from the Elixir.YourWeb.PubSub.Local0 you'll also see 2 processes "connected" to/from it.

This means that when you issue a `channel.leave()` from your front-end, your server unsubscribes this client from the "channel" you just "left", and the process that was handling it gets shut down. A channel leave is unsubscribing a specific socket (client) from that particular `channel:topic` combination. This doesn't interfere with other clients connected to that same topic. In this case, the socket (the "wire") is still connected. You can re-join the channel, or join others without having to "ask" (negotiate) to connect to the socket again.

On the other hand if you issue `socket.disconnect()` you're "plugging off the wire", and consequently unsubscribing that particular socket (client) from all the channels it was previously subscribed. This makes all processes related to that given socket to shutdown, but also doesn't interfere with other client's sockets/connections/subscriptions.

If all clients leave a given channel (either through "leave" or "disconnect"ing their sockets), you'll see that there won't be any process running for that given channel. As soon as another client joins that channel, a process for that specific client & channel:topic is created.

tldr; to answer your question:

- 1) no
- 2) no

But if you have long running processes that are spawned from inside the channel itself, that should be shut down when no client is connected to that particular channel:topic, then you will need to make sure you clean them up of course. Besides the usual monitoring capabilities of Erlang, Phoenix has a Presence interface, that allows you to track that too.